# how to convert a 3D list in numpy array without losing its properties

Tags: arrays, list, python-2.7, numpy

I am currently working on a project to use python to create CC and CI for a ocean model. I have used the interpolation from mpl_toolkits.basemap. Here is my following code:

```
sal_arr=[]
for k in xrange(len(depth)):
    salty=data.variables['salt'][k,:,:]
    salt=mp.interp(salty,lon,lat,lon_rho,lat_rho,checkbounds=False,masked=False,order=1)    
    sal_arr.append(salt)
```

When I get my interpolation data in the list, I got(part of my result):

```
masked_array(data =
[[-- -- -- ..., -- -- --]
[-- -- -- ..., -- -- --]
[-- -- -- ..., -- -- --]
..., 
[-- -- -- ..., -- -- --]
[-- -- -- ..., -- -- --]
[-- -- -- ..., -- -- --]],
         mask =
[[ True  True  True ...,  True  True  True]
[ True  True  True ...,  True  True  True]
[ True  True  True ...,  True  True  True]
..., 
[ True  True  True ...,  True  True  True]
[ True  True  True ...,  True  True  True]
[ True  True  True ...,  True  True  True]],
   fill_value = -9.99e+33)
```

However, when I transform it to numpy array using np.asarray function, it turns out to change the format of the data to:

```
array([[[  0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        , ...,   0.        ,
       0.        ,   0.        ],
    [  0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        , ...,   0.        ,
       0.        ,   0.        ],
    [  0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        , ...,   0.        ,
       0.        ,   0.        ],
    ..., 
    [ 35.85155781,  35.82556325,  35.7995687 , ...,   0.        ,
       0.        ,   0.        ],
    [ 35.86569978,  35.84589233,  35.82608487, ...,   0.        ,
       0.        ,   0.        ],
    [ 35.88255757,  35.87000866,  35.85745976, ...,   0.        ,
       0.        ,   0.        ]]
```

And, it happens to create some noise in my interpolation that I can't understand since it was ok when I plot it using the data from my list. Also, I have tried to use the function:

```
np.ma.masked_where
```

but it doesn't help too much. If anyone could suggest me any other direction I'd appreciate it.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A masked array has two attributes, a 'data' array and a 'mask' array.  In ordinary display the mask hides selected values of the data, showing '--' instead.  In your case every element is masked, so that's all you see.

That `asarray` action removes the mask, and lets you see the data.  It was all there in the masked array, but you just didn't see it.

You many need to read up on numpy masked arrays.

As to why you got a masked array, and in particular one with every value masked - you'll have to dig into the `interp` documentation.

http://matplotlib.org/basemap/api/basemap_api.html#mpl_toolkits.basemap.interp

> masked:   If True, points outside the range of xin and yin are masked (in a masked array). If masked is set to a number, then points outside the range of xin and yin will be set to that number. Default False.

Comment: Ok, I also tried to use np.ma.masked_outside and I got some good things maybe that's where I should start? Idk yet, I'll give it a try, thank you. I'll read more about the interp function.

Comment: Yes, experiment with that `masked` parameter.  May be also the `checked`.  You may need to display some of the `salty` values; is it masked?